# Monitor HPE server power status

Tags: monitoring, monitor, zabbix, health-check, zabbix-api

Hi everyone I want to monitor power status of HPE servers by Zabbix.I dont mean iLO uptime,the power on or off o the server but I didnt find any snmp for this,also ipmitool and api is not statify for my goal!Can you tell me a way to do this?!